# matrix exponentiation method for runtime optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, optimization, matrix

Can anyone please explain or suggest some good tutorial for the method of matrix exponentiation in order to optimize the solution of the problem :
[great wall of byteland](http://www.codechef.com/problems/BWALL)

The solution which I uploaded is based dynamic programming with this underlying equation :
[  f(n) = f(n-1) + 4*f(n-2) + 2*f(n-3)  ]
but the solution is giving me Time Limit Exceeded Error.

This is the code I built :

```
    #include<iostream>
    #define num 1000000007
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--){
            int n;
            cin>>n;
            if(n<=3){
                switch(n){
                    case 1:
                        cout<<1<<endl;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        cout<<5<<endl;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cout<<11<<endl;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else{
                int a=1 , b=5 , c=11 ;
                int next;
                for(int i=4;i<=n;i++){
                    next = (c + 4*b + 2*a)%num ;
                    a = b;
                    b = c;
                    c = next;
                }
                cout<<next<<endl;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Please suggest the matrix exponentiation method for optimizing the run time of the solution.

Comment: [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) might be a good starting point.

Comment: To clarify, by "matrix exponentiation", are you trying to calculate A^n, or e^A?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : I am not sure, but what is relevant to the problem

Comment: @c_sharma: If you don't know what you need, then we can't help you write the code for it...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : If you cant help, don't comment.

Comment: @DEVENDERGOYAL: No, that's not how SO works.  If the OP can't formulate a specific question, then it's not a suitable SO post.  The purpose of the comments system is to provide feedback so that the OP can improve their question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sequence defined by:

```
u(0) to u(d-1) are given
for n > d u(n)=a(1)*u(n-1)+…+a(d)*u(n-d)
```

then let A be the companion matrix defined by:

```
A(i,j) = a(d+1-j) if i = d
         1 if i+1 = j
         0 otherwise
```

and let `uinit = transpose(u(0) … u(d-1))`

You have `A^n*uinit = transpose(u(n) … u(n+d-1))` (you can verify by yourself that `A*transpose(u(n) … u(n+d-1)) = transpose(u(n+1) … u(n+d))`).

Then you can compute `A^n` in O(Log(n)) and use it to compute `u(n)`.